# Versioning to glassfish index.html in docroot for default page

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish-3

I'm using Glassfish 3.1.2 and I want version of default page(index.html in docroot) for Glassfish server, such that if I have changed some code in it then the previously cached page is refreshed.

Comment: How do you change this file? How do you deploy your application to GlassFish? Do you use an IDE? Which?

Comment: i changed the file by replacing original(index.html) file in glassfish docroot, and i'm using Netbeans IDE to develop my applications

Comment: And does it work? What do you mean by GlassFish docroot? Is this `index.html` part of your deployed application?

Comment: Yes it worked but the default index.html page is cached in client browser. And i want to apply versioning for refreshing client browser cache..